# open static html files in default browser in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Anyone been using Visual Studio Code know if there is a way to right click and open in default browser (a la Sublime Text)?
I know you can right click on the file node and "reveal in explorer" and then manually open it in a browser... but I want to save that extra 2 secs.

Comment: Here's Benjamin's comment that's on its way to be deleted as an answer: *"Please head over to http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code to vote for this feature..."*.

Answer (score 4):

Actually both the above code opens windows file explorer not BROWSER.

I am using following code which works perfectly, opens file in Chrome, while testing a static html file with Javascript.

```
{
   "version": "0.1.0",
   "command": "Chrome",
   "windows": {
       "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
   },
   "args": ["${file}"]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've got something similar in one of my projects. I've set up my tasks.json as shown below. With that in place I can type "Ctrl+P then type "task start" and hit enter to load the current HTML file in the default browser :-)

```
// Available variables which can be used inside of strings.
// ${workspaceRoot}: the root folder of the team
// ${file}: the current opened file
// ${fileBasename}: the current opened file's basename
// ${fileDirname}: the current opened file's dirname
// ${fileExtname}: the current opened file's extension
// ${cwd}: the current working directory of the spawned process
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "powershell",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "tasks": [
        // other tasks here,
        {
            "taskName": "start browser",
            "args": [
                "start", "${file}"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Remember to add this in the tasks.json file, under .settings. I also added a "showOutput": "never" to avoid opening the output view.

Comment: hi, so tasks don't live in files by themselves? all task code gets appended to tasks.json? btw, i think i read the .settings folder is now called .vscode?

Comment: @johnywhy you are correct, all tasks live in tasks.json and that is under the .vscode folder (as it is now named)

Comment: But this way, you can't have your typescript compile task ("tsc") in tasks.json?

Answer (score 3):

Press **Ctrl+Shift+P** and select **"Configure Task Runner"** command. It will open tasks.json file for you with different type of configurations. You can remove all of that and just use following code

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "command": "explorer",
    "windows": {
        "command": "explorer.exe"
    },
    "args": [
        "index.html"
    ]
}
```

Don't worry about command "explorer" it doesn't mean it will open in Internet Explorer, it will open in what is your default browser configuration. In arguments pass whatever page you would like to be open.

After you've done this, just press **Ctrl+Shift+B** and it will open "index.html" page in your default browser.

Comment: But will the file open in localhost, or will it open via the file system, having file:// as its url? Because that won't work when you access the web.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the Rafique Admed answer, here is my tasks.json file:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "chrome",
            "command": "chrome",
            "windows": {
                "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
            },
            "args": ["${file}"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I've added this to my "keybindings.json" file:

```
[
    { "key": "ctrl+alt+b",
      "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
      "args": "chrome"
    }
]
```

to open the current edited file with ctrl+alt+b (I choosed b for browser).